# Not found: object system

Tags: scala

When importing the system library in Scala using Intellij and sbt as in the example below, it fails and gives the following issue:

```
import system.dispatcher
```

Stdout:

```
[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to /Users/markramakers/Downloads/akka-websockets-demo-master/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[error] /Users/markramakers/Downloads/akka-websockets-demo-master/src/main/scala/com/amdelamar/chat/ChatRoom.scala:11:8: not found: object system
[error] import system.dispatcher
[error]        ^
```

I can't find any examples of this online with the system library - any help is welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`system` is not a library. In your examples system probably refers to an instance of `ActorSystem`. Probably your code would look somethng like this:

```scala
import scala.concurrent._
import akka.actor._

val system: ActorSytem = ActorSystem() // or however you initialise your ActorSystem
val ec: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher

...
```